# one-way one-to-many throws Hibernate Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, spring-data

I have an application that teaches the user how to play various card games. The data model that gets persisted consists of a `TrainingSession` with a uni-directional one-to-many relationship with the `Hands`.

[**EDIT**] To clarify, a `Hand` has no existence outside the context of a `TrainingSession` (i.e they are created/destroyed when the `TrainingSession` is). Following the principals of Data Driven Design, the TrainingSession is treated as an aggregate root and therefore a single spring-data `CrudRepository` is used (i.e., no repository is created for `Hand`)

When I try to save a TrainingSession using a CrudRepository, I get: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blackjack`.`hand`, CONSTRAINT `FKrpuxac6b80xc7rc98vt1euc3n` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `training_session` (`tsid`))

My problem is the 'save(trainingSession)' operation via the CrudRepository instance. What I don't understand is why the error message states that `FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES training_session (tsid))`. That seems to be the cause of the problem but I cant figure out why this is the case or how to fix it. The relationship is uni-directional and nothing in the Hand class refers to the TrainingSession.

The code, minus all the getters and setters, is:

```
@Entity
public class TrainingSession {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer tsid;
private String strategy;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private List<Hand> hands;

private int userId;

protected TrainingSession() {
}

public TrainingSession(int userId, Strategy strategy, List<Hand> hands) {
    this.strategy = strategy.getClass().getSimpleName();
    this.hands = hands;
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

while `Hand` is

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class Hand {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private int p1;
private String p1s;
private int p2;
private String p2s;
private int d1;
private String d1s;
private int trials;
private int score;

public Hand() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your TrainingSession and Hand objects first before saving the adding the hand objects to TrainingSession.

```
TrainingSession ts1 = new TrainingSession();
trainingSessionManager.save(ts1);

Hand hand1 = new Hand();
handManager.save(hand1);

Hand hand2 = new Hand();
handManager.save(hand2);

ts1.gethands().add(hand1);
ts1.gethands().add(hand2)

trainingSessionManager.save(ts1);
```

If you check your database you will find 3 tables `TrainingSession, Hand and TrainingSession_Hand`, The `TrainingSession_Hand` table references to both TrainingSession and Hand both. Therefore you need to save TrainingSession and hand before saving the relationship.

Comment: I'm assuming from the references to a `handManager` and `trainingSessionManager` in your response that you are looking at this as a Hibernate/JPA problem but it's actually a Spring-data problem. Note the use of `CrudRespository` instances. This wasn't clear in my question so I've edited it to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was assuming that when spring-data set up the DB tables, it was able to figure out and set up the uni-directional 1-to-many relationship. Apparently that isn't the case. When I configure the relationship as bi-directional everything seems to work.

To fix things I:

- removed from `TrainingSession` the `@joincolumn` annotation for hands
- in `Hands` I added a `TrainingSession` field with a @ManyToOne annotation:

  ```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "tsid", nullable = false)
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private TrainingSession tsession;
  ```
- I also added in the Hand class the getter/setter for `tsession`

I can now do a save of the entire aggregate construct using only a `TrainingSessionRepository`.